# gcloud components update permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

All of a sudden I started getting "Permission Denied" issues when trying to run any gcloud commands such as `gcloud components update` -- the issue was avoided if I ran `sudo gcloud components update` but it's not clear to my why the sudo command is suddenly required? I have actually been trying to run a GCMLE experiment and it had the same error/warning, so I tried updating components and still ran into this issue. I have been travelling for a couple days and did not make any changes since these same commands worked a few days ago. Further, I did not changed my OS (Mac High Sierra 10.13.3) -- were there any changes on the Google side that might explain this change in behavior? What is the best course of action to permanently get around this warning?

```
(conda-env) MacBook-Pro:user$ gcloud components update
WARNING: Could not setup log file in /Users/$USERNAME/.config/gcloud/logs, (IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/Users/$USERNAME/.config/gcloud/logs/2018.03.10/XX.XX.XX.XXXXXX.log')
```

after `sudo gcloud components update` I was able to kick off a GCMLE experiment, but I also get the same warning (though my job now submits successfully).

```
WARNING: Could not setup log file in /Users/#USERNAME/.config/gcloud/logs, (IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/Users/$USERNAME/.config/gcloud/logs/2018.03.10/XX.XX.XX.XXXXXX.log')
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Based on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31247129/1399222) to a similar question, you probably need to change the permissions to the appropriate directories:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config/gcloud
```

That same post suggests that permissions may have gotten out-of-whack by running a gcloud command with `sudo`.

Comment: that works - but for some reason, that error keeps coming back after some time. Could it be something with Docker / Skaffold, and that it's using `sudo` for its operations?

Comment: fantastic. Combed the internet looking for a solution and this did the trick. Thanks

Comment: this seems to happen after I update as per:  ```sudo gcloud components update```

Answer (score 10):

In most cases, the problem is not caused by the `~/.config/gcloud` directory but the installation directory of gcloud which is owned by root:

`drwxr-xr-x  20 root     staff   640 Jun 20 18:22 google-cloud-sdk`

Solution:
You must change permissions for that directory to your user from:

by:

`sudo chown -R $USER /Users/$USER/bin/google-cloud-sdk`