# gcloud cannot open path of the current working directory permission denied

Tags: permissions, gcloud

I am trying to follow some tutorial instructions to test a `gcloud API` (called `kms` in case it matters) but I must have messed up something related to permissions and I don't seem to find anything on google.

Any time I try any `gcloud ...` command I get the same error:

```
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

The issue persists after I tried:

1. `sudo gcloud kms`
2. `chown -R $(whoami) ~/.config/gcloud`
3. `chown -R $(whoami) /snap`

and all possible combinations of the above steps.

In case it matters, the VM is running Ubuntu 18.

Comment: I solved this by installing via the tarball instead of the Ubuntu snap package. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try :

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff ~/.config/gcloud/
sudo chown -R $USER /Users/$USER/bin/google-cloud-sdk
```

Or you can try to unistall gcloud, [Uninstalling Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk), and installl it again, [Installing Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install).

Related SO case [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210830/gcloud-components-update-permission-denied)